# I want all arrays data in one array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want all arrays data in one array not all arrays in one array only the data of all arrays in one array without any other array in php. I have tried to do too many things but still don't work for me.
I also tried

> json_encode

with

> preg_match

But still don't work for me.

Here is my code

```
    function fetchHashtags($getData){
        $body = $getData;
        $hashtag_set = [];
        $array = explode('#', $body);
            
            foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
                $hashtag = [];
                if (!empty($row)) {
                    $hashtag =  explode(' ', $row);
                    $hashtag_set[] = '#' . $hashtag[0];
                }
            }
            print_r($hashtag_set);
    }
```

> Output

```
        Array
(
    [0] => #Residência
    [1] => #architecture
    [2] => #casanaserra
    [3] => #mountainhouse
    [4] => #interiores
    [5] => #decoration
    [6] => #casanaserra
    [7] => #casadecampo
    [8] => #construção
    [9] => #exterior
    [10] => #rustico
    [11] => #arpuro
    [12] => #home
    [13] => #riodejaneiro
    [14] => #construir
    [15] => #casasincriveis
    [16] => #outdoor
    [17] => #arquiteto
    [18] => #casasincriveis
    [19] => #montanhas
    [20] => #archdaily
    [21] => #architecturelovers
    [22] => #arqlovers
    [23] => #arqlove
    [24] => #homedesign
    [25] => #arquiteturaedecoração
)
Array
(
    [0] => #We
    [1] => #ascaspenvswheaton
)
Array
(
    [0] => #شجریان_بشنویم...
    [1] => #۰
    [2] => #شجریان_بشنویم
    [3] => #_
    [4] => #شجریانیها
    [5] => #همایون_شجریان
    [6] => #مژگان_شجریان
    [7] => #پرویزمشکاتیان
    [8] => #موزیک
    [9] => #سهراب_پورناظری
    [10] => #محمدرضا_شجریان
    [11] => #موزیک_ویدیو
    [12] => #ایران
    [13] => #ترانه_ماندگار
    [14] => #تصنیف
    [15] => #آهنگ_ایرانی
    [16] => #هنر
    [17] => #موسیقی_ایرانی
    [18] => #شعروشاعری
    [19] => #موسیقی_سنتی_ایران
    [20] => #آواز_سنتی
    [21] => #قدیمیها
    [22] => #دلشدگان
    [23] => #دلنشین
    [24] => #سینما

    [25] => #homayoun_shajarian
    [26] => #music

    [27] => #mohamadrezashajarian

    [28] => #home

    [29] => #iran

    [30] => #shajarian
)
```

And one more thing i also want to remove some data that don't look like hashtags.

for example:

```
        Array
(
    [0] => #Residência
    [1] => architecture // This should be removed
    [2] => #casanaserra
    [3] => mountainhouse // This also should be removed
    [4] => #interiores
)
```

Comment: You mean a flat array of all array like `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]` to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes brother.

Comment: This question is Unclear because we were never offered `$getData`.  There is probably a better way than you  have been provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from my code you can use `array_merge` for merge arrays then use `array_filter` for filter value without `#` or other rules you need:

```
$array = [['1', '#2', '3', '#4'], ['5', '#6']];
$flatArray = array_merge(...$array);
$filteredArray = array_filter($flatArray, function($a) {
    if (str_contains($a, '#')) {
        return $a;
    }
});
print_r($filteredArray);
```

Result:

> Array (
> [1] => #2
> [3] => #4
> [5] => #6 )

Reference:

- [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge)
- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter)
- [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

---

After seeing your code and the context of the situation I changed things:

- Instead of use `explode` i used  `preg_split` for split `\n` and space;
- Delete `array_map` because you don't need it.

  ```
   $array = ["
   My name is Faraz shaikh i am a php developer and this my #instagram profile.Check out my #merge and my #packages with new #hashtags

   #chinese #art #colors #home #harmory #peace #handmade #paintings #etsy

   ", "
   My name is Hunain shaikh i am a php developer and this my #Facebook profile.Check out my #Berge and my #Hackages with new #tags

   #english #Kite #colours #me #memory #pee #made #paints #etsafsy

   "];

   function fetchHashtags($getData) { // This Functions takes out the hashtags from the string and put it in to arrays.
     $body = $getData;
     $hashtag_set = [];
     $array = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $body);
     $mapArray = array_map(function($a) {
       return str_replace(' ', '', $a);
     }, $array);
     $filteredArray = array_filter($mapArray, function($a) {
       if (str_contains($a, '#')) {
         return $a;
       }
     });
     return $filteredArray;
   }
   $recentNumberOfPosts = 1;
   $zeroPost = 0; //Get Post from 0 to recentNumberOfPosts | NOTE: default = 4
   $finalArr = [];
   while ($zeroPost <= $recentNumberOfPosts) {
     // fetchHashtags($hashtagRecent['data'][$zeroPost]['caption']);
     $finalArr[] = fetchHashtags($array[$zeroPost]);
     $zeroPost++;
   }
   print_r(array_merge(...$finalArr));
  ```

[Fiddle](https://onlinephp.io/c/e7492)

Comment: Hello again brother i have just created an instagram hashtag generator with the help of instagram API it's working fine but it's not giving me relevant hashtags it's just give alot's of hashtags that even not related to the query that i passed For Example I search a hashtag called "fake" the hashtags it's given me is "Find love, alloy pollu, Chinease lang, Blaw BLaw". I don't know why I have searched about it but didn't find anything that even close to it.

Comment: Please create a new question and post your code.